# NameError: name 'productName_input' is not defined (Creating a UI from a table)

Tags: python, tkinter, nameerror

I am trying to create a very basic UI. However, I am getting an error saying

`productName_input not defined`

and same with all my other inputs. I am thinking maybe the tables I created are not correct and that is why it is saying input values are not defined but I have no idea what I did wrong.

```
 #Create Tables
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE hhuschka_products(productID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,     productName VARCHAR(45). productPrice DECIMAL(8,2))")
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE hhuschka_sales (PK INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, productID INT,        unitSales INT, salesDate DATE)")

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Create UI
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue") #Color for the Window Theme
customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("System")

window = customtkinter.CTk() # Creating the basic window
window.geometry("700x300")
window.title("My first UI")
#window.iconbitmap("uccs.ico")
#window.wm_iconbitmap("uccs.ico")

tk = customtkinter
#Create Input Fields
def clear_inputs():
    productName_input.delete(0, tk.END)
    productPrice_input.delete(0, tk.END)
    unitsSold_input.delete(0, tk.END)
    salesDate_input.delete(0, tk.END)
```

Comment: As instructed in [ask], can you please write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title? For more guidance, see [How do I write a good title?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/997587)

Comment: welcome. [mre] required.

Answer (score 1):

It occurs because you are referencing input widgets (e.g. 'productName_input') before they have been created. In order to create input fields, you need to use Tkinter's 'Entry' widget or a custom widget that inherits from it, such as the ones provided by 'customtkinter'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).